# How to serve production react bundle.js built by webpack?

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, react-router, production

My app works fine in webpack development server. Now, I want to deploy it to my production server. So I built bundle.js. I tried serving the file on express server, but I can't access urls other than the root `/`.

For example, here is my react routes:

```
var Routes = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Landing}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/app" component={App}>
        </Route>
    </Router>
)
```

and express app (I put `bundle.js` and `index.html` in `./public`):

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

Landing page http://localhost:3000/ works. But the app http://localhost:3000/app doesn't. Instead, I got an error `Cannot GET /app`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to declare a "catch all" route on your express server that captures all page requests and directs them to the client. First, make sure you're including the `path` module on your server:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Then, put this before `app.listen`:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

This assumes you're inserting `bundle.js` into `index.html` via a script tag.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Found one minor typo in your solution: It should be
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname`,` 'public/index.html'));

Comment: Great! Also thank you for noticing that, I've edited the answer.

Comment: but what if my webpack output to './dist/bundle.js', while my unbundled code and index.html are in './public' ? what I need to do in prod? my express server serve static files from 'public' .. but the index.html reference script to 'dist/bundle.js' - CANNOT REACH IT ....(this is works fine with webpack's dev server)

Comment: That's the same setup I have. You just need to copy ./dist/bundle.js to ./public (make sure the path for bundle.js match relative path defined in index.html - should be ./public/dist/bundle.js in your case). You need to remember to do it in every release.

I think you can automate this with a script, webpack plugin or gulp task

Comment: Followed this method and when ever a Get request is done it returns the html file as reponse

Comment: make sure this is put as the last route in case there are api routes, which would otherwise be over-ridden.

Comment: @TRomesh I'm also getting the html file as response for js or css files. Did you resolve your issue (which I'm guessing is also mine)?

Comment: @tscizzle yeah i got it fixed by changing the order of some lines just  app.get('*', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html')); }); at the end, before other routes and server.listen(port);